# Rails Counter Cache On the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, counter-cache

I have a `model` `Task`, and each task `has_many` other tasks:

```
Class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_task, class_name: Task.name, touch: true
  has_many :sub_tasks, class_name: Task.name, foreign_key: :sub_task_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Can I add a counter cache to the number of sub_tasks each task has? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add the counter cache.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sub_task, class_name: Task.name, touch: true, counter_cache: :sub_tasks_count
   has_many :sub_tasks, class_name: Task.name, foreign_key: :sub_task_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```

You need to create a migration to add a new column named `sub_tasks_count` to the `Tasks` table.

Comment: Thanks for your insight! It Works!

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for doing what @Rubysmith wrote, you can just:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task, counter_cache: true
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Migration:

```
class AddTaskCounterToTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tasks, :tasks_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false
  end
end
```